# Spark: use of driver-memory parameter

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

When I submit this command, my job failed with error "Container is running beyond physical memory limits".

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 5G --total-executor-cores 30 --num-executors 15 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1000
```

But adding the parameter: **--driver-memory** to 5GB (or upper), the job ends without error.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 5G --total executor-cores 30 --num-executors 15 --driver-memory 5G --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1000
```

Cluster info: 6 nodes with 120GB of Memory. YARN Container Memory Minimum: 1GB

The question is: what is the difference in using or not this parameter?

Comment: are u collecting your result back to driver? like doing a count.

Comment: it performs some aggregate functions, like "SUM()". Results are then saved into Hive tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If increasing the driver memory is helping you to successfully complete the job then it means that driver is having lots of data coming into it from executors. Typically, the driver program is responsible for collecting results back from each executor after the tasks are executed. So, in your case it seems that increasing the driver memory helped to store more results back into the driver memory.

If you read the some points on executor memory, driver memory and the way Driver interacts with executors then you will get better clarity on the situation you are in.

Hope it helps to some extent.

Comment: This is a good explaination. In addition to this, I found a change in the cluster configuration, that would have affected the job: Yarn Container - minimum memory has been set to 1Gb (from 6Gb), so the driver was allocated, by default, a 1Gb memory container and no more a 6Gb container. So it becomes necessary specifying the driver-memory size to a higher value in order to execute the job, as you say.